# Filter an array of objects and return a filtered array using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm working on a coding problem for university and can't figure this out.

How can I get a new array from the above array with only applicants that have JavaScript listed as a skill using builtin methods only?

The array looks like this:

```
const NewApplicants = [
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["Docker", "JavaScript", "Ruby"] },
    { name: "Dave", skills: ["AWS", "Python"] },
    { name: "Frankie", skills: ["Azure", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Liam", skills: ["Java", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"] },
    { name: "Sara", skills: ["PHP", "AWS"] },
    { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"] },
];
```

... and the new array should look like this:

```
const NewJavaScriptApplicants = [
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["Docker", "JavaScript", "Ruby"] },
    { name: "Frankie", skills: ["Azure", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Liam", skills: ["Java", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"] },
];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like so:

```js
const NewApplicants = [
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["Docker", "JavaScript", "Ruby"] },
    { name: "Dave", skills: ["AWS", "Python"] },
    { name: "Frankie", skills: ["Azure", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Liam", skills: ["Java", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"] },
    { name: "Sara", skills: ["PHP", "AWS"] },
    { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"] },
];

const JavaScriptApplicants = NewApplicants.filter(e => e.skills.includes("JavaScript"));

console.log(JavaScriptApplicants)
```

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
>    <sub>- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter</sub>

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.
>    <sub>- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` javascript method to loop through the objects and apply this condition:

```
var filteredData = NewApplicants.filter(function(applicant) {
    return applicant.skills.includes('JavaScript');
});
```